# How to store data to dynamic fields in openerp?

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

I have created a dynamic field through field_view_get function. The problem is that when I try to store data to this field it does not get stored. The field is not showing anything. I am confused because I think I will have to make an entry for this field in my database.

1. How can this be done ?
2. Second thing is how can we set a button to fields_view_get function ?
             If I want to create dynamic fields through a button click then will it be possible through fields_view_get or not?

   Please help.
   Thanks

Comment: Please be specific and provide more information about your problem.

Comment: the info is specific now

Comment: Can you show your current code for the field? Hard to help with no code to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `store=True` in the field definition, eg:

`'level': fields.function(_get_level, string='Level', store=True, type='integer'),`

for more help use the openerp forum: https://www.odoo.com/forum/Help-1